# Is it possible to set query string from html input on submit?

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a serarch box on my website. The searchbox is a html inputbox, when i write somthing in the inputbox and submit i wish to get the input and insert it to my querystring. Normally when i do somthing like this i use the **Eval** option since i normally get the input from the serverside. Like this `<a style="color: black" href="ProductInfo.aspx?id=<%# Eval("itemId") %>">`
when i do like this the query string is equal to the id of the item i click.  
but is it possible to do it the other way where i dont get info from serverside?

i have this inputbox.

```
<input runat="server" id="txtSearchInput" name="search" placeholder="GTIN, Brand or Article nr" />
```

it is for searcing. When i press enter i wish the input from this box stored in the query string and then get redirected to anotherpage so that i can use the input from the first page. If that makes sense?

Comment: Checkout `history.pushState` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: The behaviour you describe is **what forms do** by default. What's the problem?

Comment: Is it a GET, or a POST form? Can you use JavaScript? Can you show some relevant HTML and explain what you'd like to see happen?

Comment: @CodeCaster i have updated the question with more information

Comment: Yeah so make form method "get".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a form. Make sure the name attribute matches the name of the field you want in the query string.

```
<form action="ProductInfo.aspx">
    <label>GTIN, Brand or Article nr <input name="id"></label>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```